# ReferenceError when using Javascript inside PHP's echo

Tags: javascript, php

Here's the code:

```
                <nav>
                  <ul id="alphabet" class="pagination">
                    <li><a href="#" onClick="alert(#);">#</a></li>
                    <?php
                        $letterArray = str_split(strtoupper("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"));
                        foreach ($letterArray as $s) {
                            echo '<li><a href="#" onClick="alert('.$s.');">'.$s.'</a></li>';
                        }
                    ?>
                  </ul>
                </nav>
```

When I click a letter, I get, for example:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: N is not defined
```

And if I surround $s inside alert with '' or "", it just alerts "$s". How can I "transfer" this variable to Javascript as an actual string instead of the variable literally?

Comment: Just look at the actual HTML/Javascript code that your script has generated, and the error will probably be clear right away. Now it's going to be a guessing game about the value of $s, and what the outcome might be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `foreach` code should be:

```
foreach ($letterArray as $s) {
                            echo '<li><a href="#" onClick="alert(\''.$s.'\');">'.$s.'</a></li>';
                        }
```

You are passing `$s` without `single quote` or `double quote`. So When you click on your link then its consider as `function`.

So you can pass `$s` as string with `backslash(\)`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give to JavaScript this string:

```
alert("N")
```

To achieve this, you want to print

```
alert("
```

then output the value of the variable `$s`, then output

```
")
```

This line will do it:

```
echo '<li><a href="#" onClick="alert("'.$s.'");">'.$s.'</a></li>';
```

Alternately (and better, in my opinion) is to output `json_encode` of the value, which will automatically add quotes to strings, and also escape any characters which should be escaped (like quotes):

```
echo '<li><a href="#" onClick="alert('.json_encode($s).');">'.$s.'</a></li>';
```

`json_encode` is very useful when passing data to JavaScript, as it can also handle arrays and numbers, not just strings.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather do it this way

```
                <nav>
                  <ul id="alphabet" class="pagination">
                    <li><a href="#" onClick="alert(#);">#</a></li>
                    <?php
                        $letterArray = str_split(strtoupper("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"));
                        foreach ($letterArray as $s) { ?>
                            <li><a href="#" onClick="alert('<?=$s?>');"><?=$s?></a></li>';
                   <?php } ?>
                  </ul>
                </nav>
```

Comment: This is an alternate way of doing exactly the same thing that OP did, and will result in exactly the same error that OP's code did, since you don't output any quotes either.

Comment: missing  quotes here alert("<?=$s?>");

Comment: Oh my bad sorry i missed quotes